# Unable to log out and redirect to new page from yielded layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In a 3.2.16 Rails app using Devise, we allow users to stay logged in for a number of days.  This means, of course, that if they click a link to our page (say in their bookmarks) they come right back into the app (assuming their session is still active).

For our main screen, we have a yielding layout

```
...
<body>
  ...
  <%= yield %>
  ...
</body>
```

The layout surrounding the yield includes a display of the username among other things.

And now I have a new controller:

```
class AccountSelectionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    if user_signed_in?
      sign_out current_user
      current_user = nil
    end
    ...
    render :layout => "external"
  end
  ...
end
```

When the `new` action is invoked, I want the user signed out completely, the session cleared, and the user taken to a completely different layout.  The use-case assumes the user is reaching this controller from a link in, say, an email or a page outside my app (IOW, not from a spot inside my app).

I first thought I merely had do a `sign_out current_user`(as above), but that didn't do anything obvious: the user seems to stay signed in.

The above was just my starting point. I've tried just `sign_out` (without a resource, implying all scopes), `reset session`, and `redirect_to destroy_user_session_path` (which is what our standard logout button does, a button positioned on the surrounding layout).

What I got though was my new external view (or the normal new session sign in screen, depending on the permutation of what I tried) trying to render inside the old layout (as if it was part of the yield).

I could try the Devise `after_sign_out_path_for` to help with redirect, but then I'd only want it if it was tied to this particular controller and action and I'm not quite sure how to safely accomplish that.  And now I'm not convinced it wouldn't just keep me wrapped in the surrounding layout anyway.

So, (1) is there a reason the main layout stays intact even upon a full `redirect_to` (even using `:status => 301`) that I should be able to defeat (for instance, is the yield interfering?), or (2) am I on the right track with Devise `after_sign_out_path_for` and what do I need to do to limit that behavior to just respond to this one controller action?

Thank you!
Richard

**UPDATE**:  the served page (via view source) shows the intended screen body is wrapped within the layout of the origin screen

**UPDATE 2**:  I've also tried returning a `head :reset_content` from a `before filter` along with various other things in a `before_filter`.  Still the old layout keeps rendering before it attempts to render the new page.  This is although I'm using different Chrome tabs in the test (i.e., the session stays in memory); I've tried it in Firefox too.  Same result.  The output of `rails s` shows the redirects and gives no indication that it's attempting to go through another controller first, something is triggering the layout.  Is there away to force a layout in a redirect?

Comment: A plain `sign_out current_user` should work just fine, do you think there might be any caching going on which is giving you the illusion that the user is not signing out properly?

Comment: I tried clearing my browser's local cache to check that and seemed to have the same problem, but that certainly is a reasonable thing to still consider.  It does feel like a caching issue...

Comment: In addition to clearing local cache, also try clearing rails cache in case you are using caching in your application `Rails.cache.clear`

Comment: Sorry, I've read more about Rails.cache, tried a few things including clear and it didn't seem to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is my penance for posting the question.

I just figured out that a `before_filter` was intercepting the call to the controller and redirecting it to the wrong layout before a sign-in was ever checked for.  Normally this is desired for this particular application, but I didn't realize that the filter actually was catching the redirect ahead of my controller (the logs suggested it happened at a later point).  Once I set that filter to be skipped in my controller, all was well.

Moral of the story, I need to better consider the side effects of `before_filter`s in the `ApplicationController`.

Thank you to RSB and Jasdeep Singh and everyone else who spent time considering an answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,

```
sign_out current_user, :bypass => true
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `bypass` option, thank you.  But it appears that it only applies to `sign_in`.  I tried it and got  `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`.

Comment: Can you tell me what version of devise you are using?

Comment: 2.2.8 (since we're on Ruby 1.9.3-p484, Rails 3.2.17)